# Not able to clone project on rhel

Tags: git, ssl, gitlab-ci, rhel7

I am having below configuration
OS: RHEL 7
Git Version: git version 2.18.2
Java: openjdk version "1.8.0_242"

When I am trying to clone the project I am getting below error:

```
[root@ip-XX-X-XX-XXX warfiles]# git clone https://gitlab.myproject.git
Cloning into 'ps-cs-wallet-servcies'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.myproject.git/': error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small
```

Can anyone help me here.

Thanks

Comment: *Key too small* is the kind of error that an SSL implementation produces when the key length of an RSA key is too small (hence "key too small" as the error string). You'll need to generate an RSA key-pair using a longer length. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the server you're trying to connect to is using a Diffie-Hellman key that's too small.  Diffie-Hellman is the algorithm used to establish a shared secret for secure communications as part of TLS.

If the key is too small, it could be easily guessed and then the secrecy and integrity of the connection could be compromised.  Most operating systems reject these small keys because they are insecure.

You need to talk to the system administrator of that GitLab instance and have them fix the configuration so it uses Diffie-Hellman keys of at least 2048 bits and preferably 3072 bits or more.  If that's not possible, you'll need to switch to using SSH for operations because the version of OpenSSL that Git is using won't let you connect insecurely in this way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved by setting the crypto-policies to LEGACY.

I have executed below command:

```
$ update-crypto-policies --show
```

It was set to "DEFAULT" initially.

So, I changed it to LEGACY by executing the following command.

```
$ update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misspelled CMD.
you should fix it

from

```
$ update-crypto-policies --set LEAGCY
```

to

```
$ update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your answer doesn't seem to be related to the question. Are you sure you inteded to post it here?